# Mocking an object constructor call with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I've got a code like this that I want to test before changing but I cant mock when controller calls `new dao()`.

```
//controller.js
const dao = require('./dao');

exports.callDAOProcess = () => {
  ...
  const result = new dao().getProcess();
  ...
  return result;
};

//dao.js
function dao() {
    model = require('./model');
}

dao.prototype.getProcess = function() {
    return model.getModelProcess();
}

module.exports = dao;

//model.js
exports.getModelProcess = function () {
    return 'process';
}
```

I can mock `getProcess` when testing dao.js but when I test the controller I get the real `getProcess` method. How can I mock it?
This is my test that I Expected: `mock` and Received: `process`:

```
test('Testing mock::', () => {
    const dao = require('./dao');
    jest.mock('./dao', () => jest.fn());

    dao.getProcess = jest.fn(() => ('mock'));

    const result = controller.callDAOProcess();
    expect(result).toBe('mock');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jest.mock()` method should **NOT** be used in a functional scope. It should be used in module scope.

E.g.

`controller.js`:

```js
const dao = require('./dao');

exports.callDAOProcess = () => {
  const result = new dao().getProcess();
  return result;
};
```

`dao.js`:

```js
function dao() {
  this.model = require('./model');
}

dao.prototype.getProcess = function () {
  return this.model.getModelProcess();
};
```

`controller.test.js`:

```js
const dao = require('./dao');
const controller = require('./controller');

jest.mock('./dao', () => {
  const mDao = { getProcess: jest.fn() };
  return jest.fn(() => mDao);
});

describe('63144781', () => {
  test('Testing mock::', () => {
    const daoIns = new dao();
    daoIns.getProcess.mockReturnValueOnce('mock');
    const result = controller.callDAOProcess();
    expect(result).toBe('mock');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/63144781/controller.test.js (10.615s)
  63144781
    ✓ Testing mock:: (4ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controller.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.868s
```

Comment: No, jest.mock can be used in local scope. But a dev needs to be aware of what's required to make it working as intended. It's not hoisted and all modules that depend on it should be re-imported.

Comment: @EstusFlask You need to use [jest.doMock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) in functional scope.

Comment: It's works the same way as jest.mock inside functions, only takes 3 keypresses more to type. I suppose it can be recommended for cases where it was expected to hoist inside functions (like the OP did).